# How to get Customer Id while exporting customer details in magento backend

Tags: customer, magento2.3.1, importexport

I wish to download Customer Id while exporting customer details in Magento back-end?

**`Systems -> Export->Customer Main file`**

Can anybody guide me , how to include customer id while export customer data

Answer (score 0):

There would be no way unless we do override a class

app/code/Vendor/CustomerImportExport/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CustomerImportExport\Model\Export\Customer" type="Vendor\CustomerImportExport\Model\Export\Customer"/>
</config>
```

app/code/Vendor/CustomerImportExport/Model/Export/Customer.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\CustomerImportExport\Model\Export;

use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;

class Customer extends \Magento\CustomerImportExport\Model\Export\Customer
{

    const COLUMN_ENTITY_ID = 'entity_id';

    /**
     * Permanent entity columns.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $_permanentAttributes = [
        self::COLUMN_ENTITY_ID,
        self::COLUMN_EMAIL,
        self::COLUMN_WEBSITE,
        self::COLUMN_STORE
    ];

    /**
     * Export given customer data
     *
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $item
     * @return void
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function exportItem($item)
    {
        $row = $this->_addAttributeValuesToRow($item);
        $row[self::COLUMN_WEBSITE] = $this->_websiteIdToCode[$item->getWebsiteId()];
        $row[self::COLUMN_STORE] = $this->_storeIdToCode[$item->getStoreId()];
        $row[self::COLUMN_ENTITY_ID] = $item->getId();

        $this->getWriter()->writeRow($row);
    }
}
```